# session based messages not working in classes

Tags: php, class, session

I have a main file (framework.php) that `require`s a few classes. For simplicity of my question lets assume only messages with the class `Messages` and automate with the class `Automate`. The messages class stores session messages that appear to the user on the frontend whenever they refresh their page .etc. When I add a message in `Automate` I do so via `$msg = new Messages; $msg->add('s', 'Hello World!');` However I keep repeating `$msg = new Messages` everytime I want to add a `$msg`, and because this is messy, I want to just call the class once. So I initialize the class in the constructor like so:

```
class Automate
{
    protected $msg;
    //public $connection;
    public $cke;
    public $debug = false;
    public $disallow_insert;
    public $bImgUp = BACKEND_IMAGE_UPLOAD_PATH;
    public $fImgUp = FRONTEND_IMAGE_UPLOAD_PATH;
    public function __construct() {
        global $disallow_insert;
        $this->disallow_insert = $disallow_insert;
        $this->cke = (bool) self::ckeCheck();
        $this->msg = new Messages();

    }
```

and in my main file I add it `$msg = new Messages();` so I can just call the display function `echo $msg->display();`

However this method does not work (no errors, but still), the only thing that seems to work is when I initialize the `$msg = new Messages();` before every add or display. What am I doing wrong?

I should mention I'm using [this session based message script.](https://github.com/plasticbrain/PHP-Flash-Messages/blob/master/class.messages.php)

UPDATE:
I have determined the the messages are getting added by commenting out the `clear` function in the messages class. It almost seems as though the variable is getting unset before displaying.

Comment: How do you access your `$msg` variable from outside your `Automate` class, via getter?

Comment: $msg = new Messages(); Remember the messages are stored in a session variable (see script)

Comment: You can try using `debug_print_backtrace()` inside your `Messages::clear()` method, to see, when and why it is actually called.

Comment: Oh thanks for that little function! Didn't know about this. I get: #0 Messages->clear() called at [C:\xampp\htdocs\fagard_designs\neou_cms\framework\classes\messages.php:114] #1 Messages->display() called at [C:\xampp\htdocs\fagard_designs\neou_cms\update_pages.php:20]

Comment: Does that mean clear is getting called before the display? I mean that makes no sense it only gets called at the end of display!

Comment: I see, that `display()` function does call `clear` after messages `display()`; So this is perhaps an intended behavior?

Comment: Yes it is, it removes the possibility of the same display message being called on yet another reload. So its there the first time a person goes on a page with $msg->display after a message is added. But, that is not the issue. The issue is that nothing displays at all since I changed methods, however the variable is added to the session!

Comment: It definitely has something to do with the classes. But idk what..

Comment: Please, stop using global variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after researching OOP practices. I made the messages class a singelton via:

```
public static function getInstance()
{
    static $instance = NULL;
    if (NULL === $instance) {
        $instance = new static();
    }

    return $instance;
}
```

and in my classes

```
var $msg;
public function __construct() {
    $this->msg = Messages::getInstance();
}
```

I figure the messages class needed to be constructed once, not multiple times which is why the function clear kept being called!